# I am having troubles to split a list in Python, how can I solve it?

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas

This is the error: Error message in Python 'list' object has no attribute 'str'

I am trying to split the data. Here is my code:

```
df = {'Name':['XPTO1 - SS1','XPTO2 - SS2','XPTO3 - SS3','ID':['276','323','2045']}
```

When I try to split the first column using the "-" separator

```
df['Name1'], df['Name2'] = df['Name'].str.rsplit('-', 1).str
```

I get the following error message:

```
'list' object has no attribute 'str'
```

Any idea how to figure this out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your return on `df['Name']` is the list under the `Name` tag.

```
['XPTO1 - SS1','XPTO2 - SS2','XPTO3 - SS3']
```

You just want to access the element like:

```
df['Name'][0]
```

which is

```
XPTO1 - SS1
```

Then, you can split that like:

```
df['Name1'], df['Name2'] = df['Name'][0].split(' - ')
```

which gives:

```
df['Name1'] = 'XPTO1'
df['Name2'] = 'SS1
```

If you want lists of all of the items on the left side of the dash and on the right side of the dash, you can do it in place like:

```
df['Name1'] = [item.split(' - ')[0] for item in df['Name']]
df['Name2'] = [item.split(' - ')[1] for item in df['Name']]
```

which gives:

```
['XPTO1', 'XPTO2', 'XPTO3']
['SS1', 'SS2', 'SS3']
```

Comment: No problem. Glad I could help. :)

Answer (score 0):

df['Name'] is a list containing ['XPTO1 - SS1','XPTO2 - SS2','XPTO3 - SS3'] , not a string. You might want to try to iterate through each of the items in your list.

Try:
    for item in df['Name']:
    df['Name1']= item.rsplit('-',1)